# Passing a function pointer from C code to a C++ library as an argument

Tags: c++, c, function

What is the correct way to pass a function pointer from C code to a C++ function as an argument? Simple example:

**foo_c.h**

```
typedef int (*int_func)(int);
extern void foo(int_func);
```

**foo.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include "foo_c.h"
void foo(int_func);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**foo.cpp**

```
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>

void foo(int_func)
{
    std::cout << "foo : int_func(5) : " << int_func(5) << std::endl;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "foo_c.h"

int timestwo(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

int main()
{
    foo(timestwo);
    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all: main.c libfoo.so
        gcc main.c -L`pwd` -lfoo

libfoo.so: foo.cpp foo.h foo_c.h
        g++ -fPIC -shared -o libfoo.so foo.cpp

clean:
        rm -rf a.out libfoo.so
```

This code compiles and runs, but gets the incorrect output:

```
foo : int_func(5) : 1
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
void foo(int_func)
```

You have a variable type but no name, and you are not calling the function.

Change it to:

```
void foo(int_func myfunc)
```

You would have realized your function wasn't being called if you had added some debug output to it:

```
int timestwo(int x)
{
    std::cout << "timestwo(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
    return x*2;
}
```

In your version the output doesn't happen, so the function wasn't called, so int_func was not being interpreted as a function.

Comment: well that turned out to be a silly mistake. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
void foo(int_func)
{
    std::cout << "foo : int_func(5) : " << int_func(5) << std::endl;
}
```

You're not calling the function.

Change it to:

```
void foo(int_func fn)
{
    std::cout << "foo : int_func(5) : " << fn(5) << std::endl;
}
```